# Calculating the interest portion of a loan between two dates

Tags: interest-rates, excel

The IPMT function in Excel calculates the interest portion of a loan between 2 dates. Is  this a closed loop formula? Or are the payments projected and the interest summed up?

I need to implement such a function in Python and hoping there is a more elegant approach compared to projecting the payments and summing it up.

Comment: This post https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-the-equation-that-excel-uses-for-the-ipmt/2b2a7c0d-f39b-4fdc-a713-ba2810b3d166 has closed formulas, but I haven't checked them so I don't know if they are accurate

Comment: I'm sure that's right, but will check, thanks